# How to make the functions start one after another?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am creating rock, paper, scissors game. And after the battle I want the result to be displaying on the screen for 5 seconds then start counting backwards from 5. Both functions should start one after another but I don't know how to do it. I tried different variations using `setTimeout()` but apparently I am missing something. I did my research before asking the question but couldn't find anything helpful.

JS:

```
let elements = [
    "../img/scissors.png",
    "../img/rock.png",
    "../img/paper.png",
];
const startBtn = document.querySelector('.start')
const startImg = document.querySelector('.all-elements')
const rules = document.querySelector('.rules')
const phase1 = document.querySelector('.phase-1')
const phase2 = document.querySelector('.phase-2')
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper img')
const opponent = document.querySelector('.opponent-choise')
const result = document.querySelector('.result')
let clicked = false
let time = 5


startBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    phase1.style.display = "none"
    phase2.style.display = "block"
})


for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    let me = imgs[i]
    me.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if(clicked == false){
            clicked = true
            chooseSign(me, imgs)
            countDown()
        }
    })
}

function chooseSign(b, c){
    c.forEach((a)=>{
        a.style.display = "none"
    })
    b.style.display = "block"
    b.style.cursor = "auto"
    displayOpponent()
    checkForWinner(b, opponent)
}

function displayOpponent(){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    opponent.style.display = "block"
    opponent.src = elements[random]
}

function checkForWinner(me, opponent){
    let meSrc = me.getAttribute('src')
    let opponentSrc = opponent.getAttribute('src')
    if(me.src == opponent.src){
        let a = "Draw!"
        showWinner(a)
    } else if
        (meSrc == elements[0] && opponentSrc == elements[2] ||
         meSrc == elements[1] && opponentSrc == elements[0] ||
         meSrc == elements[2] && opponentSrc == elements[1])
         {
        let a = "You win!"
        showWinner(a)
    } else {
        let a = "You lose!"
        showWinner(a)
    }
}

function showWinner(a){
    result.textContent = a
    setTimeout('showWinner()', 5000)
}

function countDown(){
    result.textContent = time
    time--
    if(time == -1){
        return
    }
    setTimeout('countDown()', 1000)
    result.textContent = time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript `setTimeout()` function is asynchronous in order not to freeze all the js code during the delayed time interval. As you have not provided a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I could only guess what you intended. Here is the modified code:

```
let elements = [
"../img/scissors.png",
"../img/rock.png",
"../img/paper.png",
];
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper img')
const startBtn = document.querySelector('.start')
const startImg = document.querySelector('.all-elements')
const rules = document.querySelector('.rules')
const phase1 = document.querySelector('.phase-1')
const phase2 = document.querySelector('.phase-2')
const opponent = document.querySelector('.opponent-choise')
const result = document.querySelector('.result')
let clicked = false
let time = 5


startBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    phase1.style.display = "none"
    phase2.style.display = "block"
})


for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    let me = imgs[i]
    me.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        if(clicked == false){
            clicked = true
            chooseSign(me, imgs)
        }
    })
}

function chooseSign(b, c){
    c.forEach((a)=>{
        a.style.display = "none"
    })
    b.style.display = "block"
    b.style.cursor = "auto"
    displayOpponent()
    checkForWinner(b, opponent)
}

function displayOpponent(){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    opponent.style.display = "block"
    opponent.src = elements[random]
}

function checkForWinner(me, opponent){
    let meSrc = me.getAttribute('src')
    let opponentSrc = opponent.getAttribute('src')
    if(me.src == opponent.src){
        let a = "Draw!"
        showWinner(a)
    } else if
        (meSrc == elements[0] && opponentSrc == elements[2] ||
         meSrc == elements[1] && opponentSrc == elements[0] ||
         meSrc == elements[2] && opponentSrc == elements[1])
         {
        let a = "You win!"
        setTimeout(showWinner(a), 5000);
    } else {
        let a = "You lose!"
        setTimeout(showWinner(a), 5000);
    }
}

function showWinner(a){
    result.textContent = a;
    setTimeout(countDown(),  5000);
}

function countDown(){
    result.textContent = time
    time--
    if(time == -1){
        return
    }
    result.textContent = time
}
```

Please provide a minimal reproducible example (i.e. include your relevant html/css) in case there are any further problems.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is wondering I solved the problem. Here is the code for the ones who need the answer. Sorry if I haven't provided the answer in the most optimal way.

JS:

```
let elements = [
    "../img/scissors.png",
    "../img/rock.png",
    "../img/paper.png",
];
const startBtn = document.querySelector('.start')
const exitBtn = document.querySelector('.exit')
const startImg = document.querySelector('.all-elements')
const rules = document.querySelector('.rules')
const phase1 = document.querySelector('.phase-1')
const phase2 = document.querySelector('.phase-2')
const imgs = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper img')
const opponent = document.querySelector('.opponent-choise')
const result = document.querySelector('.result')
let clicked = false
let time = 4 //put one more second to start on time
let refreshedTime = time
let a


startBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    phase1.style.display = "none"
    phase2.style.display = "block"
    result.textContent = "Choose a sign!"
})

exitBtn.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    if(clicked == false){
        phase1.style.display = "block"
        phase2.style.display = "none"
    }
})

for(let i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++){
    let me = imgs[i]
    me.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        setTimeout(()=>{
            if(clicked == false){
                clicked = true
                time = refreshedTime
                chooseSign(me, imgs)
                setTimeout(countDown, 2000)
            }
        }, 1000)
    })
}

function chooseSign(b, c){
    c.forEach((a)=>{
        a.style.display = "none"
    })
    b.style.display = "block"
    b.style.cursor = "auto"
    displayOpponent()
    checkForWinner(b, opponent)
}

function displayOpponent(){
    let random = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)
    opponent.style.display = "block"
    opponent.src = elements[random]
}

function checkForWinner(me, opponent){
    let meSrc = me.getAttribute('src')
    let opponentSrc = opponent.getAttribute('src')
    if(me.src == opponent.src){
        a = "Draw!"
        result.style.color = "yellow"
    } else if
        (meSrc == elements[0] && opponentSrc == elements[2] ||
         meSrc == elements[1] && opponentSrc == elements[0] ||
         meSrc == elements[2] && opponentSrc == elements[1])
         {
        a = "You win!"
        result.style.color = "green"
    } else {
        a = "You lose!"
        result.style.color = "red"
    }
    showWinner(a)
}

function showWinner(a){
    result.textContent = a
}

function countDown(){
    result.style.color = "black"
    time--
    if(time == -1){
        clicked = false
        imgs.forEach((img)=>{
            img.style.display = "block"
            img.style.cursor = "pointer"
        })
        opponent.style.display = "none"
        result.textContent = "Choose a sign!"
        return
    }
    setTimeout('countDown()', 1000)
    result.textContent = time
}
```